# JavaScript Function Skipping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that should run a function every 5 seconds depending on what one was previously run however it seems to be skipping every second one.

```
let i = 0;
function testOne()
{
    $("#two").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#three").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#four").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#five").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#one").fadeIn().css("display","block");
    $("#iOne").addClass("btn-active");
    $("#iTwo").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iThree").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iFour").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iFive").removeClass("btn-active");
    i++;
}
function testTwo() {
    $("#one").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#three").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#four").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#five").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#two").fadeIn().css("display","block");
    $("#iTwo").addClass("btn-active");
    $("#iOne").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iThree").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iFour").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iFive").removeClass("btn-active");
    i++;
}
function testThree() {
    $("#one").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#two").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#four").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#five").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#three").fadeIn().css("display","block");
    $("#iThree").addClass("btn-active");
    $("#iTwo").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iOne").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iFour").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iFive").removeClass("btn-active");
    i++;
}
function testFour() {
    $("#one").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#two").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#three").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#five").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#four").fadeIn().css("display","block");
    $("#iFour").addClass("btn-active");
    $("#iTwo").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iThree").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iOne").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iFive").removeClass("btn-active");
    i++;
}
function testFive() {
    $("#one").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#two").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#three").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#four").fadeOut().css("display","none");
    $("#five").fadeIn().css("display","block");
    $("#iFive").addClass("btn-active");
    $("#iTwo").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iThree").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iFour").removeClass("btn-active");
    $("#iOne").removeClass("btn-active");
    i = 0;
}
window.setInterval(function()
    {

        if(i === 0) {
            testOne();
            i++;
        } else if (i === 1) {
            testTwo();
            i++;
        } else if (i === 2) {
            testThree();
            i++;
        } else if (i === 3) {
            testFour();
            i++;
        } else if (i === 4) {
            testFive();
            let i = 0;
        }

    }, 5000);
```

The functions are displayed after "let i = 0" however I chose not to put them in as they are too long. All they do is run some jQuery code before i++; or let i = 0; on the fifth function.

Do you know why this could be the issue?

Full JS Code - https://hastebin.com/icalefafoy.js

- Ben J

Comment: `let i = 0;` -> `i = 0;`, otherwise looks good, maybe you call the whole code more than once?

Comment: I tried that but still the same error.

Comment: It works just fine aside from what Jonas pointed out. I'm unable to duplicate http://jsfiddle.net/pzejvrfc/1/

Comment: Forgot to mention. It takes double the time the setInterval should take before skipping the code.

Comment: @BenJ Okay, but the function isn't or is skipping for you? You have to be more specific with what the problem is - and since we can't duplicate, please show us more of your code.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/icalefafoy.js

Answer (score 3):

You increment `i` twice, once in the interval code and once in the function itself:

```
 function testOne() {
   //...
   i++
 }

 //...
 testOne();
 i++
```

just don't do that.

Comment: Ah I see now. Thank you.
ISSUE FIXED

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing the variable `i` twice on each iteration of your interval, once in the function you call and once in the interval function itself, which is why it's skipping. Remove the `i++` from your other functions.

```js
let i = 0;
function testOne()
{
 console.log("one");

}
function testTwo() {
 console.log("two");

}
function testThree() {
 console.log("three");

}
function testFour() {
 console.log("four");
}
function testFive() {
 console.log("five");
}
window.setInterval(function()
    {

        if(i === 0) {
            testOne();
            i++;
        } else if (i === 1) {
            testTwo();
            i++;
        } else if (i === 2) {
            testThree();
            i++;
        } else if (i === 3) {
            testFour();
            i++;
        } else if (i === 4) {
            testFive();
            let i = 0;
        }

    }, 5000);
```